# how save ploted lines on an image as a .mat file

Tags: matlab, plot, save, mat

I have some images and I'm showing them and plot lines on them, how I can save the original images with the plotted lines as a .mat file in Matlab?

```
figure,imshow(geo.^0.25,[]);hold on;
plot(1:512,size(geo,1)-aa,'w','LineWidth',3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getframe](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) and [frame2im](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/frame2im.html):

```
h = figure; %Keep the figure's handle in h
imshow(geo.^0.25,[], 'border', 'tight'); %Plot image without borders
hold on;
plot(1:512,size(geo,1)-aa,'w','LineWidth',3);
I = frame2im(getframe(h)); %Get the displayed "frame", and convert it to image.
save('I.mat', 'I'); %Save I (RGB matrix) to mat file.
```

Comment: thanks, and how i can value the pixels that the line plotted on them? i mean i want macke all the pixels that the line plotted on them a white pixel.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Do you want the line to cover only white pixels? Do you want the line color to be white? What is the format of `geo` image, is it Grayscale or RGB (colored)?

Comment: I think you better post a new question, and make a reference (link) to the above post. I recommend you to upload a sample input image, and a sample output image (mark something with MS paint). Remove irrelevant parts like `geo.^0.25`.

Comment: Do you have license to Computer Vision Toolbox? I think it's easier to draw line directly on the image (as a matrix) instead of using `plot` (with plot, you need to use `frame2im(getframe(h))`, and it's less robust. See [insertShape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertshape.html).

Answer (score 0):

While the output is a fig instead of a mat file, you may want to take a look at the matlab `savefig` command. It allows you to safe figures and open them later in MATLAB.